# Strange amsmath + multicol empty space at the beginning of first column

Tags: amsmath, multicol

I need to use multicol environment to write equations in 2 columns on the page, but for some reason it looks like it's inserting a newline in first column. Any way to avoid this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\addtolength\textwidth{3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{1 2} = min\{d^{4}_{1 4}+d^{4}_{4 2},d^{3}_{1 2}\} = min\{4+\infty,3\} = 3\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{1 3} = min\{d^{4}_{1 4}+d^{4}_{4 3},d^{3}_{1 3}\} = min\{4+\infty,4\} = 4\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{2 1} = min\{d^{4}_{2 4}+d^{4}_{4 1},d^{3}_{2 1}\} = min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{2 3} = min\{d^{4}_{2 4}+d^{4}_{4 3},d^{3}_{2 3}\} = min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{3 1} = min\{d^{4}_{3 4}+d^{4}_{4 1},d^{3}_{3 1}\} = min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{3 2} = min\{d^{4}_{3 4}+d^{4}_{4 2},d^{3}_{3 2}\} = min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: empty space]
P.S. I absolutely can't use align or split environment for this task, because that would require major changes in Python script that generates this LaTeX file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you use with Python script the symbol `\min` instead of `min`? It is very important to add a complete code to understand well your problem.

Comment: yeah, sure, thanks for tip. the Python code just makes LaTeX document from strings as plain text, so it's pretty easy to change. as for the code - I think it's not very important in this case, as I'm asking for specific LaTeX feature.

Comment: If the Python tool produces such dubious code, then it's time to abandon it.

Comment: @egreg yeah, no, thanks, because I am writing this Python tool myself and I am not going to redo it, I will need it exactly one time and then I'm 95% sure that I won't touch it once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always an error to start a paragraph with displayed math, the double column setting makes the spurious empty paragraph more apparent. You can suppress it in this case with `\noindent`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\addtolength\textwidth{3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{1 2} = \min\{d^{4}_{1 4}+d^{4}_{4 2},d^{3}_{1 2}\} = \min\{4+\infty,3\} = 3\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{1 3} = \min\{d^{4}_{1 4}+d^{4}_{4 3},d^{3}_{1 3}\} = \min\{4+\infty,4\} = 4\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{2 1} = \min\{d^{4}_{2 4}+d^{4}_{4 1},d^{3}_{2 1}\} = \min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{2 3} = \min\{d^{4}_{2 4}+d^{4}_{4 3},d^{3}_{2 3}\} = \min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{3 1} = \min\{d^{4}_{3 4}+d^{4}_{4 1},d^{3}_{3 1}\} = \min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}d^{4}_{3 2} = \min\{d^{4}_{3 4}+d^{4}_{4 2},d^{3}_{3 2}\} = \min\{\infty+\infty,\infty\} = \infty\end{equation*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as Sebastiano commented under the question all the `min` should be `\min` here, never set multi-letter operators in the default math italic, which is designed to separate letters and make them look like a product of variables.

Comment: In my case this actually added more space on top of that first column :|